# How to place chaincode using hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I am very new to Hyperledger Fabric. I have cloned the fabric-samples repository and built a network using it. The problem I have is, should I place chaincode inside the chaincode folder of the fabric-samples?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should if you are using the examples but you can change the path as you like.
I recommend you to read the documentation first.

> [Choosing a Location for the Code](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4ade.html#choosing-a-location-for-the-code)